# Strip @ from API response with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working with an api that provides a response like this:

```
    {
    "statuses": {
        "status": [
            {
                "@array": "true",
                "@id": "1",
                "@uri": "https://api.com/people/statuses/1",
                "name": "Member",

            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to use javascript to strip the @ out of the key names.  Eg "@id" to "id".  How can I do this?

Comment: `v = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v).replace(/"@(.+?)":/g, '"$1":'));` if not an object, but a string in the beginning - omit `JSON.stringify` step

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually iterate and rename each key and remove the original attribute in a given status. Something like

```
response.statuses.status.forEach(function(status) {
  var keys = Object.keys(status),
      keyCount = keys.length;

  for (var j = 0; j < keyCount; j++) {
    var thisKey = keys[j];

    status[thisKey.replace('@', '')] = status[thisKey];

    delete status[thisKey];
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you just want `response.statuses.forEach` at the beginning there.

Comment: His response has a weird structure, but it is indeed response.statuses.status that is the array.

Answer (score 1):

Other than looping through the keys and building a new object like everyone else has stated, you could get really crazy and do something like this:

```
// convert to string, if not already a string response
var responseStr = JSON.stringify(myObj);

// REGEX AWAY THE STUFF
responseStr = reponseStr.replace(/@/g, "");

// convert to obj
myObj = JSON.parse(responseStr);
```

Although, if any of your data has `@` in it naturally, it would get regex'ed out. I know, It's crazy. Thought it might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripSymbol(obj) {
    var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
    if (type === '[object Array]') {
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            stripSymbol(obj[i]);
        }
    } else if (type == '[object Object]') {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
            if (key[0] === '@') {
                var newKey = key.substr(1);
                obj[newKey] = obj[key];
                delete key;
                key = newKey;
            }
            stripSymbol(obj[key]);
        });
    }
}

stripSymbol(data);
```

This will recursively crawl through and object and remove the '@' at the beginning of any keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just rename the keys within javascript objects, but you could always extend the response object.  Something like this would work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < statuses.status.length; i++){
  var status = statuses.status[i];
  status.array = status["@array"];
  status.id = status["@id"];
  status.uri = status["@uri];
  // could also delete properties here... see below...
}
```

That would give you what you were looking for, although all the properties with '@' would still exist.  You could take it a step further and delete those properties, though.

```
delete status["@array"];
delete status["@id"];
delete status["@uri"];
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.  Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score -2):

well first of all array is probably a reserved word for any javascript parser but ignoring that try this...

```
statuses.status[0].array = statuses.status[0]["@array"];
delete statuses.status[0]["@array"];
```

the reason you need to do this is because javascript doesn't support renaming keys.

Comment: If you're going to downvote how about you explain why it doesn't help?

Comment: Ah I see... you wanted it done for you. I get it. I made the mistake of thinking you just wanted to know how it worked.

Comment: But it does. It solves it specifically and in the same exact way as the other two answers only with less hand-holding

Comment: I know. Thanks though

Comment: For what it's worth, array isn't a keyword in JavaScript.